# how do i count byteCount in read method of InputStream

Tags: java, android, io, inputstream

i want to download a file through InputStream from some offSet,
i know that i can do this by read method of InputStream but it requires a parameter byteCount
but i don't know how to calculate byteCount for read Method

**My Code is**

```
         try {
                URL url;
                url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                c.setConnectTimeout(1000000);
                c.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();
                Log.i("fileSize", lenghtOfFile + "");
                File file = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                                + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, "4k1.jpg");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                Log.v("Place", "trying...");
                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
                Log.v("errorPart", c.getURL().toString());
                if (c.getURL().toString().contains("404"))
                    Log.v("Error", "404 Error");
                Log.v("Place", "1st attempt success");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                Log.v("Place", "Download started!");
                int on = 0;
                    while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                        Log.v("is", "running "  + len1);
                    }
                Log.v("Place", "Download Finished!");
                fos.close();
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Please try to explain your answer, i am newbiee

Comment: Have you looked at the Byte-Range header? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving

Comment: Your byte count = 1024 * No Of Iterations of the While Loop.
It is just the last iteration, which may not provide a full 1024-Byte buffer. But generally it must work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it how many bytes it can read.  This is to prevent the read() method copy data over memory that it shouldn't.  You should therefore pass the size of the `buffer`.  In the code above this will be 1024.  You may want to use `private static int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024` and use this constant in both the `new` and `read()` so that if you change the size of the buffer you don't forget to change the parameter to the `read()` function as well.

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

...

byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int len1 = 0;
Log.v("Place", "Download started!");
int on = 0;
while ((len1 = is.read(buffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
    Log.v("is", "running "  + len1);
}

...
```

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is generating

Comment: Maybe, but this does answer what the byteCount parameter is for and gives an example of one mechanism for providing a value.

Comment: @user3811952 ... but trying to be a little more helpful - Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: `while ((len1 = is.read(buffer, 100, 1024)) != -1) {`
this is giving error!

Comment: You're telling it to copy (up to) 1024 bytes into the buffer, starting at offset 100.  This would require buffer to have a capacity of 1124 bytes.  In this case use `read(buffer,offset,(BUFFER_SIZE-offset)))` where `offset=100;`.

Comment: @user3811952 You will also have to change your `fos.write()` accordingly, of course.

Comment: @user3811952 I can't tell you that, because I don't know what you need to save to the output file.  But you can work out how to do it from the explanation of the parameters in my answer.  Also, don't get confused between the offset into the input stream that you mention in your question and the offset into the buffer that is a parameter of the `read()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly use the class, [`CountingInputStream`, provided by Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html). This class has been perfectly designed to match your requirment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to provide **byteCount** for **read** method. Using `is.read(buffer))` will simply read out **1024 bytes** (since defined by the length of your buffer array) at every round till **-1** is returned.

Comment: but i want to set offSet and i if i put 1024 in byteCount it gives `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: yes it will throw exception because your offset value should not be more than the total bytes available in the stream. But why do you want to get this done with offset and byteCount? I don't see any valid reason for that.

Comment: because i want to start downloading from specific byte

Comment: Then I would suggest you to make sure that your offset value does not exceed `lenghtOfFile` value. For example: `is.read(buffer, offset, (lenghtOfFile - offset))`

Comment: @waqaslam can u tell me why sometimes the read(buffer) method return a number less than 1024 whereas i specified buffer size to 1024bytes???

Comment: @hamid_c because at some point your stream may not have all the 1024 bytes available to read, so it will simply fill-in the remaining number of bytes it has read. And if it returns -1 then it means all the data is read and there's nothing left in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct access to the file size from HttpURLConnection You can use the nio cache under your file stream In a one-time generated file.